# Navigate directories in Python without changing the current directory?

Tags: python, directory

```
C:/Root
  |__WinPython
  |     |_WinPy
  |           |_Python(Working Directory)
  |                 |_sample.py
  |__SDK
      |_SparkHome
```

Consider I'm in the Working directory mentioned above.

```
os.getcwd()
   C:/Root/WinPython/WinPy/Python
```

Now I need to set the Spark Home from the sample.py file in current directory, which should be like

```
Spark_Home="Root/SDK/SparkHome"
```

I achieved this using the command,

```
import os
spark_home = os.chdir("../../../SDK/SparkHome")
```

This sets the spark home for me successfully but also changes the current working directory.

```
os.getcwd()
  C:/Root/SDK/SparkHome
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this without changing the current working directory?

Comment: Well , `spark_home = os.chdir("../../../SDK/SparkHome")` should set `spark_home` to `None` since `chdir()` does not return anything. It does change the current working directory.

Comment: Yes, i've set the spark home like this

        spark_home =os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'SDK/SparkHome') after os.chdir("../../../SDK/SparkHome"). But this doesn't seems to be the right way.

Comment: Just do whatever you need to do in the directory of your choice. Then whatever scripts\files you're saving or manipulation just provide the path and they'll be sent there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that you do not want to change the current working directory for `spark` to work, and you just need to set the `spark_home` variable correctly. Then just use `os.path.join()` directly, you do not have to do `os.chdir()` before that. And then use `os.path.abspath()` to get the absolute path.

`os.path.abspath` can handle relative paths as well, so you can use `'..'` and `'.'` , etc in it.

Example -

```
import os.path
spark_home = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'../../../SDK/SparkHome'))
```